# Autopopulate CC Field in Case Email Feed Action Based On Earlier Email's Recipients

Tags: email, servicecloud, casefeed

My users often receive emails (via Email-To-Case) which have additional recipients CC'd on them. But when the user responds to the email, from the standard (not custom) Case Feed Email Action, the CC field is not automatically populated and the additional recipients email addresses have to be manually entered.

[image: Email Action screenshot]

Is it possible to automatically populate the CC field, with the email addresses of recipients of previous emails from the same Case?

Note: My users do have Service Cloud licenses and are using the Service Cloud Console.

The [Customizing the Email Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.case_feed_dev.meta/case_feed_dev/case_feed_dev_guide_email_publisher.htm) documentation only lists the options for setting field level security for the CC field.
The [SendEmailQuickActionDefaults Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_QuickAction_SendEmailQuickActionDefaults.htm)  documentation includes a getInReplyToId() method but doesn't mention the CC field.
While Emails will have a [dedicated object](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_sales_productivity_email_platform_features.htm) after the Summer ,16 release, the [Release Notes](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_apex_new_classes_methods.htm#rn_apex_new_classes_methods_new_classes?edition=&impact=) don't seem to suggest that the field will become accessible.

Comment: Are you using the Service Console? If so, not certain if this would work, but have you tried creating a macro for this functionality?

Comment: @crmprogdev thanks for the suggestion, the additional recipients email addresses aren't stored in a field though so I don't think that the macro wouldn't be able to retrieve them. I'll check.

Comment: Gotcha, you'd need to pause and select them I take it? Or are you wanting it to find the CC field from the previous email which the macro may not support?

Comment: @crmprogdev the latter. In case the recipients have changed since the 1st email was received.

Comment: Gotcha. I don't work a lot with Service Console, but have some familiarity, thus the suggestion as a means of trying to help. Good luck!